# Sort globally with mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

I have 10 HDFS files with numbers (integers).
When I do sorting on them with mapreduce, each reducer's output is nicely sorted. However, what if I want all numbers sorted globally? something like: the first output file has the largest numbers, and the last output file has the smallest numbers...

The options I have thought of are:

- use a single reducer, which may defeat the purpose of mapreduce
- download and merge-sort all locally...

Any better solutions?
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the terrasort example.
There they first do a sample of the data to create a partitioning scheme that ensures global sorting ofthe end result.